# Find another function over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ which is the same as $x^2-x+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have this polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_5$. How do I get another polynomial which coincide with this also over $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

$$f(x) = x^2-x+1$$

I think that $g(0), g(1), g(2), g(3), g(4)$ must be same as $f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)$, but how do I do it?

Comment: You can try using that over $\Bbb F_5$ every element is such that $x^5=x$. So adding $x^5-x$ to any polynomial will not affect its value.

Comment: In fact, the ring of *polynomial functions* over $\Bbb F_q$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_q[X]/(X^q-X)$, that is, every polynomial function is uniquely determined modulo the ideal spanned by $X^q-X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)+x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$. This idea will work for any finite field.